# Как удалить одинаковые элементы 1 массива из 2 массива.

Tags: массивы, php

```
$array = array();

        $arr1 = array('эл 1','эл 2','эл 3');
        $arr1 = array('эл 4','эл 1','эл 6');

            foreach ($arr1 as $el1) {
                foreach ($arr2 as $el2) {
                    if ($el1 != $el2) {
                        array_push ($array, $el1);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Пробовал этот код - но он работает. Возможно, есть ли такая функция, которая удаляет одинаковые элементы 1 массива из 2 массива? То есть нужно прогнать массив, с проверкой второго массива. И если этого элемента во 2ом массифе нет - закидывать в общий массив.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

есть функция [array_diff](http://www.php.ru/manual/function.array-diff.html)  - Вычислить расхождение массивов. Думаю это то что надо

Answer (score 3):

**UPD**

```
$arr_1 = array('1', '2', '3', '10');

$arr_2 = array('4', '1', '6', '10', '2', '17', '46');

foreach($arr_1 as $name => $value)
{
    if(!in_array($value, $arr_2))
    {
        array_push($arr_2, $value);
    }

    $array = array($arr_2);
}

print_r($array);
```

Comment: Элементы массива могут располагаться в рандомном расположении. Типа
$arr1 = array('1','2','3', '5');
$arr1 = array('4','1','6');

Comment: да есть косяк в скрипте, недопрочел... сейчас апну!

Answer (score 2):

`array_diff , array_intersect`

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array();

$arr1 = array('эл 1','эл 2','эл 3');
$arr2 = array('эл 4','эл 1','эл 6');

for($i = 0; $i < count($arr1); $i++)
{
    for($j = 0; $j < count($arr2); $j++)
    {
        if($arr1[$i] == $arr2[$j])
            continue 2;
    }

    array_push($arr, $arr1[$i]);
}
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Элементы массива могут располагаться в рандомном расположении. Типа 

$arr1 = array('1','2','3', '5'); 
$arr2 = array('4','1','6');

Comment: И? Работает все